# jQuery: Firefox does not recognize dblclick()!

Tags: jquery, firefox

last few months I tried to develop some web application running JS, jQuery and PHP and most tricks I found here (thanks) and all scripts I tested by using Chrome. What to say, it worked until I decided to change testing browser. I decided FF v. 47 and expected it will works like fine as I saw in GC but not! Firefox simply doesn't recognize dblclick() on cell of dynamically created table.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

"Troublemaker" is this code:

```
$("#mytable").on("dblclick", "tr", function(e) {
  var idcel = $(event.target).attr('id'); 
  var idrow = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id'); 
  console.log('you clicked row with id= '+idrow); 
  console.log('id of clicked cell is: ' +idcel);
//...
  });
})
```

Is it up to me or FF has some dark secrets I don't know yet? Thank you.

Comment: FF doesn't use global event model. You are passing `e`, so use it: `var idcel = $(e.target).attr('id');`  which btw could just be: `var idcel = e.target.id;`

Comment: Wouldn't be asking this question if you had opened the dev tools console and looked at error thrown.

Comment: @charlietfl I just tested it, and if no modal is used (e.g alert()), the event isn't fired on FF, even fixing `event` error. See: https://jsfiddle.net/8h7gLgps/

Comment: you have `e` as argument but used `event.target` in line 2,other than that I think its ok!

Comment: For me there is a bug. You should report it to FF dev team

Comment: @A. Wolff: Thank you, I tried your solution and it works for me! Until now I didn't know I could write mentioned code part on this way! But still it's dark cloud over FF due this "anomaly".
You saved my weekend! God bless ya man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to fast suggestion of A. Wolff, above code shall be as follows:

```
$("#mytable").on("dblclick", "tr", function(e) {
  var idcel = e.target.id;
  var idrow=e.currentTarget.id;
  console.log('you clicked row with id= '+idrow); 
  console.log('id of clicked cell is: ' +idcel);
//...
   });
})
```

All credits to A. Wolff. Thank you man.